# Include page url in php error_log

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I'm working on sorting out all my php errors. I've just setup so that all errors go into one log so I can view them. The problem is that I can't really see what page someone trying to access that gave them an error.

Of course I can see the file where the error was generated, but these are often includes used on other pages - so I can't really see what URL a person was attempting to view when this error was displayed, so I can't really replicate the problem.

Any suggestions? Is it possible to include the actual page URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customize the error message with set_error_handler()

Someone already posted its code to address a similar issue : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#95206